# how to retrieve values from JSON array response

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to fetch ahmedabad,surat from location key. I am giving an output

```
$jsonResponse = Zend_JSON::decode(substr($response['body'], 9));

print_r($jsonResponse['result']);

//output :Array ( [0] => Array ( [location] => ahmedabad [id] => 18x49 ) [1] => Array ( [location] => Surat [id] => 18x42 ) )
```

I went to through the solutions on many websites but cudnot get how to accomplish this. Please I appericate your help. I hope i have given essential details.

Comment: Learn about arrays: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop in elements:

```
foreach($jsonResponse['result'] as $val){
    echo $val['location'];
}
```

Comment: thanks @mihailorga , once agian you have done it..Glad :)

Comment: Remember when someone answers your questions and solves your issue to accept the answer that suits you best, same thing applies for any question you have in the past.

Comment: It is the more nicer/more general way, as I suppose you want to work with more data than what you provided in the example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$jsonResponse['result'][0]['location'] // 'ahmedabad'
$jsonResponse['result'][1]['location'] // 'Surat'
```